# error: occurred while running subprocess Cordova while adding platform iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-ios

When I try to run

```
ionic platform add ios --verbose
```

it fails with the following error:

```
An error occurred while running subprocess Cordova.
```

I got an extra info on an error by running cmd with `--verbose` flag and I think this could be the reason for the error.

```
No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
```

also when it is installing plugins while adding platform

> No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
>
> No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".

this is the log I am getting.

can anyone help with this?